# Initializing a vector every loop

Tags: c++, vector

When I declare a vector, it is by default padded to zero. As a part of a simulation I would like it to initialize every iteration in a loop. what is the correct and efficient way to do it?

I would like to address two cases:

1. I would like it to be zeroed to a known value, i.e nSteps

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   using namespace std;
   const int nSteps = 10000;
   const int nReal = 10;
   int main()
   {
       for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<nRealization; i++)
       {
           vector<double> v(nSteps);
           for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j<nSteps ;  j++)
           {
               //stuff going on with v
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The length is not defined ( it is given with a function that uses `push_back` )

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   using namespace std;
   const int nSteps = 10000;
   const int nReal = 10;
   int main()
   {
       for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<nRealization; i++)
       {
           vector<double> v;
           // some function that uses push_back gives v its length

           for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j<nSteps ;  j++)
           {

               //stuff going on with v
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you make your examples clearer? Please include what you expect the end state of the vector to be in each case; i.e. what length and contents it should have.

Comment: @DanHulme ,  there is already an answer for the first case

Comment: @DanHulme, what exactly is not clear at the second case?

Comment: It is not clear to me what state you want v to have after the sought-after function returns.

Comment: the vector v will have a length that will be determined dynamically, the length will be different every time, once it will be 5, other time 2000, unlike case 1 where it will always be with length nSteps = 10000, OK?

Comment: If you are pushing data into the class why re-zero it?  just call `clear()` and then start refilling it.

Comment: @NathanOliver , so you suggest to clear it and declare it again in every loop?, will it be correct in terms of memory?

Comment: No move the vector outside the loop.  When you reach the end of the loop `clear()` the vector and then refill it at the start of the loop.  This has the added advantage of not have to allocate storage again as long as the next run doesn't exceed the capacity of the previous allocation.  This does mean that the vector might be bigger than you need but I don't think that will be an issue for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver ,sometime the vector is almost zero length, and sometime very very long....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) stated in their answer if you do not want to have the vector reallocated every loop then you can move the vector out of the loop and then use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to re zero the vector

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> v(nSteps);
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<nRealization; i++)
    {
        std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0); // reset to zero
        for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j<nSteps ;  j++)
        {
            //stuff going on with v
        }
    }
}
```

In you second example I would suggest that you declare the vector outside of the loop like in the first example and then you would just need to empty the vector each iteration and you can do that with [`std::vector::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> v;
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<nRealization; i++)
    {
        v.clear(); // erase all elements
        // refill vector with function that uses push_back
        for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j<nSteps ;  j++)
        {
            //stuff going on with v
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `clear()` will not change the capacity of the vector so this will cut down on the number of memory allocations you  as you get to reuse the capacity each iteration.  Now some times you could be using a vector with a large capacity for just a few elements but the next time you need that larger capacity it will be there.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is your friend. Whenever you want to do a thing, simply read through a list of standard library utilities until you find [the one you want](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)!

```
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

This is essentially equivalent to an old-fashioned `memset`, but with added type safety.

Comment: @LightRacesinOrbit I've rephrased the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but you could use

```
 v.clear(); 
 v.resize(nSteps, initialValue);
```

To reinitialise a vector to a given size and value. 
I think this would work for both your cases, and you would not need the the `push_back`.

But as lightness says, the documentation is your friend.